# Command: for | It won't accept my variable in skip=%var% option

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Well, I am kinda stuck on the following part of my code.
This program will count the number of lines in the file usernames_list.txt. On each line there is a name of a folder I want to enter. I want that program to enter each folder in my list, create a file called test_1 and then go to it's parent folder. This should be reapeated until it reaches the end of the list.
Am I doing it right? :/
For some reason the "skip" option won't accept my variable.

```
    for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< usernames_list.txt') do set lines=%%C
    set times=0
    set /A skip_value=%lines%-(%lines%-%times%)
    :redo
    FOR /F "skip=%skip_value%" %%b IN (usernames_list.txt) DO (
    cd %%b
    echo > test_1
    cd ..
    set /A times=%times%+1
    if /i {%times%}=={%lines%} (goto continue)
    goto redo
    )
    :continue
    pause
```

Comment: The if /i {%times%}... inside a for loop will not do what you want.  The %var% expansion is done at the time of parsing of the loop not during the execution.  You want to use delayed expansion if you want to test the value of variable times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As currently written, `set /A skip_value=%lines%-(%lines%-%times%)` will always evaluate to 0 because times = 0.

The SKIP value *must* be >= 1. Setting SKIP=0 results in a syntax error.

It seems to me your logic for computing skip_value is flawed. But even if you fix the logic, you still have to worry about values that are <= 0. I handle that situation by defining a SKIP variable with the entire option text only if the value is >= 1.

```
set "skip="
if %skip_value% geq 1 set "skip=skip=%skip_value%"
for /f "%skip%" %%b in (usernames_list.txt) ...
```

You might need additional FOR /F options. That is not a problem. For example:

```
for /f "%skip% delims=" ...
```

Comment: Ooops, I didn't know that the SKIP value must be >= 1. I searched everywhere and nowhere was something like that stated. Thank you! It's not a problem from me to skip the first line as the first line may not necessary be a folder name if that produces the problem. Thanks again. :)